# unexpected workspace transposition

Tags: spaces

I am using yosemite and take advantage of workspaces.  Occasionally, my workspace locations get transposed.  E.g. workspace 2->3 and workspace 3->2.  I use ctr-N where N is the workspace that I want to go to.  What is the hot key or command that causes this to happen?  It happens to me every once in a while and I can never seem to figure out what I have done to cause this to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly System Prefs > Mission Control > Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use.

[image]

Comment: I had it checked, so presumably unchecking it will solve my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome - I'm pretty sure that will be it